# Does a greeting label add value besides first sign up screen?

Tags: usability, gui-design

I've seen a common practice, in some places, that every intranet web app, or desktop app, shows a label somewhere stating "Welcome: [name of person]".

I understand that such a welcome message has some value inmediatly after a person signs up for a website, but not every time he/she logs in.

Heres a mockup:

[image]

- Does this add value?
- Where does this custome come from?
- Does any usability source recommend it?

I would personally prefer to add the name of the user besides the log out button like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding greeting message would not hurt after user logs-in especially if there are plenty of white spaces. This could be thing of the past but still functional and valuable. Others are trying to improve it by using user's image profile. Others just use the user name when there's not enough room for the greetings.

Again its a matter of preference and how you layout and design your page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has ongoing value. Its a good way to show/remind users that they are logged in to your site.  For example, Amazon.com uses "Hello " at the top of the account menu to help indicate that you are signed in. It's a good state reminder, and particularly helpful if there's any chance a user might have multiple accounts (such as a business account and a personal one).
As for the wording... your example with "Log out (user name)" does serve the same basic purpose. At that point its a matter of the tone or voice you want to set for your site.  Saying hello or welcome is a bit more conversational and friendly than showing their name in parentheses like a data field.